# “en termes” ou “en terme” ?

Tags: expressions, pluriel

Dans le sens “en matière de”, l'expression “en terme(s) de” s'écrit-elle au pluriel ou non ?

Exemple : *“en termes de lourdeur, l'administration française est remarquable”*. À ne pas confondre, donc, avec *“être en (bons/mauvais/…) termes avec”*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Historiquement, l'expression est *en termes de*, toujours avec le pluriel. Mais cette expression signifie « dans les mots de », « en utilisant le vocabulaire de ». Pour reprendre les exemples cités par le [*Trésor de la Langue Française*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/terme) (²B) :

> On appelle, en termes d'atelier, croquer une tête, en prendre une esquisse, dit Mistigris d'un air insinuant (Balzac, Début vie, 1842, p. 401).
>   Il fut impossible au vidame de Maulle de trouver ce qu'en termes de justice on nomme un alibi (Villiers de L.'I.-A., Contes cruels, 1883, p. 266).

L'[Académie française](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/questions-de-langue#32_strong-em-en-termes-de-au-terme-de-em-strong) proscrit l'utilisation de cette locution dans le sens de « en matière de », qu'elle considère comme un anglicisme. Cela n'empêche pas d'aucun [académicien](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/node/2829) de l'employer, au pluriel.

Grevisse considère cet emploi comme courant mais fautif, et préconise le pluriel (voir [cet article](http://www.langue-fr.net/spip.php?article146)).

La [Banque de dépannage linguistique](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=3438) québecoise considère cet emploi comme « critiqué par certains auteurs ». Elle préconise elle aussi le pluriel, et argumente que l'on ne peut pas considérer comme un anglicisme, dans la mesure ou les sens de l'expression sont apparus sensiblement en même temps en anglais et en français (une courte excursion sur Google Ngrams et Google Books semble corroborer cette affirmation : le sens de « en matière de » est apparu au 20<sup>e</sup> siècle pour *en termes de* comme pour *in terms of*).

Maintenant, si on pousse plus loin, on trouve de nombreux usages où *terme* est au singulier. Par exemple, sur le [site web du *Monde*](http://www.lemonde.fr/), il y a une minorité significative de *en terme de*. (Attention, je n'ai pas de chiffres précis, et les articles sur le site sont moins relus que ceux dans l'édition papier.) La proportion augmente si l'on élargit la recherche aux blogs, ce qui fait penser que *en terme de* est moins correcte.

Answer (score 4):

Le [TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/) ne répertorie pas cet emploi pourtant courant. Je pense qu'il s'agit de [Terme² B. 2.](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/terme)

> *En termes de.* Dans la terminologie, le vocabulaire propre à une discipline, un art, une science, une pratique. *En termes d'art, de biologie, de chimie, d'informatique, de mathématiques, de médecine. On appelle, en termes d'atelier, croquer une tête, en prendre une esquisse, dit Mistigris d'un air insinuant* (Balzac, Début vie, 1842, p. 401)

ce que semble confirmer la partie historique

> 1547 *en termes de* « en matière de, selon les règles de » (J. Martin, Archit. Vitruve, p. 5 vods IGLF)

Donc visiblement, **au pluriel**. [Le ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=en%20terme%20de,%20en%20termes%20de&year_start=1800&year_end=2012&corpus=7&smoothing=3) est d'accord
[image: Google ngram pour en terme de, en termes de]

Answer (score 2):

Règle : On n’écrit jamais « en termes de » sans un « s ». Il y a en effet toujours plusieurs « termes » dans l’usage de cette expression.

Exemples : En termes de droit, en termes de voyage, en termes de sport…

Attention, on confond souvent la signification de « en termes de ». Cette expression signifie « dans le vocabulaire de », « dans le langage de » et ne veut pas dire « en ce qui concerne », « en matière de », « sur le plan de ». Cette confusion est sûrement due à l’expression anglaise « in terms of » qui elle a le sens de « en matière de ».

Pour plus de précisions : http://www.lalanguefrancaise.com/en-termes-de-en-terme-de